# How to swipe view up to reveal a menu at the bootom of the screen using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I would like to create a toolbar/navigationbar that appears at the bottom of the screen when the user swipes up on the screen. I would like it to have a bit of resistance in the same way pull to refresh works at the top of a tableview. However I am not using a tableview in my app.

I have tried searching for anything that would point me in the right direction, however the search terms seem to return results either about swiping to delete or facebook style menus.

How would I achieve the swipe up to reveal? Any advice or links to helpful tutorials would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: so you want to show a view when you swipe up? try to animate the view according to your swipe!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the menu view to the view but outside of the screen. Add a `UIPangestureRecognizer` to the view. In the action of the pan recognizer, change the frame of the menu view according to the pan distance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
How could I add a sticky resistance effect that would make it seem less static in a similar fashion to the pull to refresh?